# Running R within an iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, r

I'm trying to figure out if this is doable

I know there's a way to run Python or Lua scripts within iOS. Also, I know there are already projects that make this easy to do with libraries and bridging components.

The question is - has this also been done for the R language? I've been looking around online but have only seen posts by people that have done this on a jailbroken environment. Also according to my understanding this does not go against the iOS developer license agreement as section 3.3.2 has been altered to allow running any code that's bundled along with the application binary.

Any suggestions? Directions to try?

Comment: Given the misunderstandings of those attempting to answer your question, perhaps you could clarify even more in your question exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I rephrased the question a bit, feel free to pitch in and suggest an edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/r-programming-language/id540809637?mt=8

Also you can run windows applications on iOS:

http://www.technobuffalo.com/2013/10/17/microsoft-app-turns-your-ios-device-into-a-windows-8-1-device/

http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=12872

However, I have not tried these personally.

Comment: I mean to run R code within my iOS app. Not run R using an existing app. This means I need libraries, frameworks, etc...

Comment: did you found some way to implement this?